# How to ignore first NA value when finding linear trend across raster stack

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a large raster stack. I want to calculate a linear trend for each pixel in the raster stack. However, some of the pixels in the first layer of that stack have NAs. This is causing an error. How can I ignore the nas and still compute the linear trend? Below are my attempts commented out. Please help!

```
  s<-stack(lapply(files,raster))
  y<-1:nlayers(s)

  #trend_fun=function(x) {lm(x[!is.na(x)] ~ y[!is.na(x)])$coefficients[2] }
  #trend_fun=function(x) { lm(x ~ y)$coefficients[2] }
  #trend_fun=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ lm(x[2:21] ~ y-1)$coefficients[2] } else { lm(x ~ y)$coefficients[2] }}
  
  #trend_fun=function(x) {
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  y <- y[!is.na(x)]
  lm(x ~ y)$coefficients[2]
  }

  slope <- calc(s, trend_fun)

Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function
```

Comment: I understand you want something like `calc(s, \(i) coefficients(lm(i ~ seq(i)))[2])`. What kind of error did your code throw?

Comment: Thank you - error is added to the original post.